# User Campaign/Source/Medium always "direct/not set" on Firebase Analytics when logging event using react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I've follow this [installation instruction](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage) and can see logged events in Debug View as a screenshot below.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7uY4.png)

**What I Expected:**
Able to classifying conversions by campaign.

**What I Got:**
Unable to classifying conversions by campaign. because, there's no campaign data in conversions report. (please check a screenshot below)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybi45.png)

**Remark:**
I already triggered "campaign_details" event with source/medium/campaign information before logging any conversion events.

**Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to provide**.